# Person suspects someone of being a vampire but no one believes them

Tags: story-identification, books, vampire

I'm looking for a book I read a few years ago, and I can't remember the name of it. It's about a person who works on a farm for money and suspects someone of being a vampire, but when they try to tell people, no one believes them. Eventually this person gets turned into a vampire, and at the end of the book, they are found by some kids when they are sleeping in their coffin inside of a large house. The kids alert the town's people and they set fire to the house. I think this book was in flashback form and the flashback was from a long time ago, but the vampire is telling the story in more modern times. Can anyone help me find it?

Comment: Possibly the opening to Interview with the Vampire, by Anne Rice?

Comment: No, I don't think that was it. I think it was a free ebook

Comment: @user4376 have you read interview with the vampire? as it does sound like a possibly fit.  You may have got a ripped off copy been passed as free, it happens unfortunately.  If you haven't read there is a preview on amazon http://www.amazon.co.uk/Interview-Vampire-Number-Chronicles/dp/0751541974/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1426175044&sr=1-1&keywords=interview+with+a+vampire#reader_0751541974

Comment: Well I think that this story isn't as much of a book as it is a story. I've thought about reading Interview with the vampire, but I heard its not the very best for someone my age.